# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined Jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Probably this question has been answered many times before, but i can't find anything that related to my code.

Everything works properly, when the menu nav is open, etc. the `smooth scrolling` works as well, except when i click the `arrow-down` to go the the next section, smooth scrolling doesnt work. 
I have been looking at it and trying to figure it out for a while but i am unable to do so.

I am still learning jquery and javascript.
A full DEMO of this code in use can be found **[HERE.](http://jnremache.justthingsido.com/)**
Open dev tools and you will see the errors in the console.

**EDIT** 
added..

```
.arrow-down-wrapper a[href^="#"]
```

to

```
$('nav.mobile-nav a[href^="#"], .arrow-down-wrapper a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
...
}
```

Smooth scrolling not works for the 'arrow-down', but i am still getting 
'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined'

`console.log(target);` outputs the correct targets. #Home, #about, etc..

This is the code i have:

```
    //smooth transition to sctions when links in header are clicked

    function onScroll(event){
      var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('nav.mobile-nav a').each(function () {
        var currentLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
          $('nav.mobile-nav a').removeClass("current");
          currentLink.addClass("current");
        }
        else{
          currentLink.removeClass("current");
        }
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

            $('nav.mobile-nav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(document).off("scroll");

                $('nav.mobile-nav a').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('current');
                });
                $(this).addClass('current');

                var target = this.hash;
                $target = $(target);
                $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
                }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: If the element on which the `position` is called does not exists then the error could come...

Comment: so log the value of `currentLink.attr("href")` - (`console.log(currentLink.attr("href"))`) and `console.log(this.hash)` before calling `position` to find out which element is causing the error

Comment: @ArunPJohny `(console.log(currentLink.attr("href"))` outputs, all three tags, `#about, #home, #porfolio`.   and  `console.log(target)` outputs, every tag i click on. `#HOME, about, ...etc`

Comment: before the error is thrown in the console which value is printed

Comment: The problem is in your html, you have the following markup for the `Contact` link

   `<a href="contact">Contact Us</a>`

You are missing the `#` in the href

Comment: @ArunPJohny The following:  `#home, #about, #porfolio` those are the links that are in my nav menu, which displays: block with `toggle('slide')..after clicking on the menu button

Comment: @ArunPJohny that `Contact` links meant to be a link for another page, which i havent created yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99758/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-guille).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the code wasn't specific enough. The loop was iterating through all the items in the list, that is all the links that where #tags, and links to other pages. That is the reason i was getting the error of top not defined, that item it was looking for didn't exist. `a[href^="#"'` after adding that, loop only iterated the items with # ID tags.

**Commented the changes i made**

//smooth transition to sctions when links in header are clicked

```
    function onScroll(event){
      var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
      $('nav.mobile-nav a[href^="#"').each(function () { //added a[href^="#"] so that the loop only iterates over the elements with the ID tag
        var currentLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
        console.log(currentLink.attr("href")); //log
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
          $('nav.mobile-nav a').removeClass("current");
          currentLink.addClass("current");
        }
        else{
          currentLink.removeClass("current");
        }

      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

            $('nav.mobile-nav a[href^="#"], .arrow-down-wrapper a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(document).off("scroll");

                $('nav.mobile-nav a').each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass('current');
                });
                $(this).addClass('current');

                var target = this.hash;
                $target = $(target);
          console.log(target);
          $('html, body').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 100
                }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                    window.location.hash = target;
                    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
                });

            });
        });
```

Comment: @henkvanBoeijen I tried marking it as an answer but it wouldn't let me

Answer (score 0):

That is a style so the value, in javascript, would need to be `.style.top` not just `.top`. That is why you are getting 'undefined'. There is no `top` property assigned to the object you are using.

I don't use jQuery but, in javascript, to retrieve the top property, you could do something like:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var b = a.style.top;
console.log(parseInt(b,10)); //cause b will be equal to 'nnpx' and parseInt removes the 'px'
```

However, this doesn't read any top value set in CSS. You need to set the value with javascript in order to read that. There is a way to read the value set in a CSS stylesheet but I don't recall how.

Comment: Maybe i am to tired, but i cant figure it out

Answer (score -1):

I don't actually get the problem.
Opening the dev tools i have some errors but the smooth scroll on your website works quite fine for me.

Have a look at this jsfiddle i made:

https://jsfiddle.net/p4x3d2dn/1/

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#section_home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#section_about">About</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#section_team">Team</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#section_gallery">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#section_contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<section id="section_home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</section>
<section id="section_about">
  <h1>About</h1>
</section>
<section id="section_team">
  <h1>Team</h1>
</section>
<section id="section_gallery">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
</section>
<section id="section_contact">
  <h1>Contact</h1>
</section>
```

Adding other links (such as a scroll down arrow) is just a matter of adding the correct **href** attribute to the .scroll tag:

```
<a class="scroll" href="#section_whatever_you_want">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
</a>
```

*A slightly different approach must be taken if you have  custom generated sections and you are not in control of the DOM*

This is all the **javascript** you need:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".scroll").on("click", function() {
    //event.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this).attr("href");
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });

});
```

Comment: It looks looks complicated because aside from smooth scrolling to where it is being directed too, it also highlights the current menu item it is on. For example if it is on the about section the about link in the menu is highlighted. Aside from that it also updated the URL. And as well as when I scroll down the page without clicking on anything. I think my code is much simpler than the ones you would find else where

Comment: I didn't mean to sound offensive and I apologize if it seemed that way.
The features you mentioned does not seem to work in the DEMO you posted. Is that the issue you're trying to fix?

Comment: That is correct. And I fixed it already. If you see the answer you will see the changes I made. It's just that I am unable to select it as an answer for about 8 more hours.

Comment: Okay, i'm glad you found it.
Maybe you already know but you could also try FullPage:
http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/